# Changing asp.net session state mode drops session data

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

We are using asp.net session to store data about the progress of the long-term process executed by the user.
For some reasons we had to temporarily switch from **InProc** mode to the **SQLServer** sessionstate mode. As a result the data being written into the session

```
public static void UpdateProgressInSession(HttpContext context, string guid, int progress)
    {
        var sessionItem = context.Session["ProgressStatus"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
        if (sessionItem == null)
        {
            context.Session["ProgressStatus"] = new Dictionary<string, int> { { guid, progress } };
            return;
        }
        sessionItem[guid] = progress;
        context.Session["ProgressStatus"] = sessionItem;
    }
```

is not readable under the session with the **same ID** but from the **another thread**.

```
 public TestRunnerSession GetSessionProgress(HttpContext context, string guid, int testSessionsCount)
    {
        var testRunnerSession = new TestRunnerSession()

        //this variable is always null from now even after session was updated
        var sessionItem = context.Session["ProgressStatus"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
        if (sessionItem != null && testSessionsCount >= MaxSessionsCount && !sessionItem.Keys.Contains(guid))
        {
            testRunnerSession.Status = Currently.Waiting;
            testRunnerSession.ProgressValue = 0;
            return testRunnerSession;
        }
        int value;
        if (sessionItem != null && sessionItem.Count != 0 && sessionItem.TryGetValue(guid, out value))
        {
            testRunnerSession.Status = Currently.InProgress;
            testRunnerSession.ProgressValue = value;
            return testRunnerSession;
        }

        //sessionItem has not been initialized yet
        //This part of the method is always fired now
        testRunnerSession.Status = Currently.InProgress;
        testRunnerSession.ProgressValue = 0;
        return testRunnerSession;
    }
```

This code works well while in the **InProc** mode.
What could be the source of the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find very hopefully this link where aspnet sessions states are very well explained http://books.google.it/books?id=gGF75LnxUpIC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=get+session+from+sql+server+mode+in+aspnet+in+separate+thread&source=bl&ots=Vi1mv-FD2H&sig=etNVHJpOMr7B8z5Q7nLHujS8dHM&hl=it&sa=X&ei=JdhFU9mJE4LftAa9sYGYCA&ved=0CJYBEOgBMAg#v=onepage&q=get%20session%20from%20sql%20server%20mode%20in%20aspnet%20in%20separate%20thread&f=false

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue isn't in session...
Look into this code:

```
var sessionItem = context.Session["ProgressStatus"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
```

Probably this initialization wrote into 'sessionItem' **null** because cann't cast it to Dictionary at once. Try to verify what type you have when getting 'ProgressStatus'